# Response body is empty from Rest service

Tags: java, rest, web-services, jax-rs

I am testing a Rest service which is written by JAX-WS. I execute my service and service returns an entity and I am setting this entity in response with status ok, At the end service returns status OK with code 200 but response body is empty. I debugged my code and the line below is executed without problem. What can be the reason for it ?

```
final Entity entity = getEntity(); // i confirmed that entity is initialized and not null.
Response.ok(entity).build()
```

My entity class is simple Pojo:

```
public interface Entity{

    Integer getAge();
    void setAge(Integer age);
}

public class EntityImpl implements Entity{
   private Integer age;

   ....

   // setter getter
}
```

Comment: You have not posted enough code for us to help you. Please post your resource class. Also can you show the code for `getEntity()`

Comment: how did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Response.ok().entity(entity).build();
```